# AccessDenied when calling StartBackupJob using Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, access-denied

Have a lambda function to start an on demand backup programmatically.

but as soon as the lambda is invoked it returns:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
> StartBackupJob operation: Insufficient privileges to perform this
> action.

Proper request and role is defined for the start_backup_job function.

```
client = boto3.client('backup')
response = client.start_backup_job(...) // the role used here works well in the console and creates backups
```

Also, the lambda function role has the following policies:

```
{
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "backup:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "backup:StartBackupJob",
                "backup:CopyFromBackupVault"
            ],
            "Resource": 
                "arn:aws:backup:*:*:backup-vault:*",
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "backup:DescribeRecoveryPoint",
                "backup:StartCopyJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:backup:*:*:recovery-point:*"
        }
```

What could be wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

had mistakenly used the arn instead of vault name.